# Cannot access domains hosted on Nginx

Tags: nginx, centos, web-server

I have taken the task to try and figure out how to use Nginx to host my websites (previously using IIS). I purchased a VPS running CentOS 8. I have been trying to configure Nginx to run two different domains on the same port.

I have examined and followed multiple guides online and I am still unable to target both websites.

After installing Nginx and configuring the service, I created two conf files in */etc/nginx/conf.d* directory:

**website1.com.conf**

```
server {
    listen 80;
    root /var/www/website1.com;
    index index.html index.htm;
    server_name website1.com www.website1.com;

    location / {
            try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
    }

}
```

**website2.com.conf**

```
server {
    listen 80;
    root /var/www/website2.com;
    index index.html index.htm;
    server_name website2.com www.website2.com;

    location / {
            try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
    }

}
```

I then also created two basic index.html files in the directory */var/www/website(1|2).com*

Initially I had to remove the default server block from the nginx.conf file to get it to load anything other that the default site.

**nginx.conf**

```
# For more information on configuration, see:
#   * Official English Documentation: http://nginx.org/en/docs/
#   * Official Russian Documentation: http://nginx.org/ru/docs/

user nginx;
worker_processes auto;
error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;
pid /run/nginx.pid;

# Load dynamic modules. See /usr/share/doc/nginx/README.dynamic.
include /usr/share/nginx/modules/*.conf;

events {
    worker_connections 1024;
}

http {
    log_format  main  '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] "$request" '
                      '$status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
                      '"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for"';

    access_log  /var/log/nginx/access.log  main;

    sendfile            on;
    tcp_nopush          on;
    tcp_nodelay         on;
    keepalive_timeout   65;
    types_hash_max_size 2048;

    include             /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    default_type        application/octet-stream;

    # Load modular configuration files from the /etc/nginx/conf.d directory.
    # See http://nginx.org/en/docs/ngx_core_module.html#include
    # for more information.
    include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;

}
```

I have been trying to load the website using this URL with my IP address and also localhost (http://0.0.0.0/website1). It is my understanding Nginx matches incoming requests first against port then by server name, both of my config files are on listening on port 80.

I would really appreciate some direction on what I am doing wrong here as everything I have seems to follow documentation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use the hostname (e.g. website2.com) in the URL. That hostname should be in DNS or, for testing, in /etc/hosts or equivalent for your workstation OS.

**Edit:**
Here is how the web browser is working. When you have an URI (URL), the string is split in [multiple components](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_Resource_Identifier#Generic_syntax) (protocol, user, password, host, path, query, fragment...)

*name resolution* - Host is the one we are interested. It can be a hostname or an IP. If it is a hostname, the name will be resolved by the resolver library located on the web client machine. This library by default will use `hosts` file, then DNS to resolve the name.

*virtual host aka nginx Server Blocks* - the web browser will make a HTTP request that will contain `Host:` header to tell the web server which hostname he is trying to access. That is why you need to have a hostname and not an IP if you want to test those servers.

Comment: Thanks for the comment, so I believe this will allow me to test the nginx config within the  VPS. One thing I am however wondering is how could I access the website externally from my own machines over the web? I might be misunderstanding how nginx works but I believed if I type http:\\x.x.x.x/ServerName, it should have been able to resolve it

Comment: To make it work from outside for anyone, you must use the DNS hostname and the server needs to be added to a public DNS server. For testing only you can add an "ip hostname" entry into /etc/hosts or c:\Windows\System32\Drivers\etc\hosts, but this will work only on the machines where you have edited that file.

Comment: I have two domains that I own, I can update the A records to point at the IP address of my webserver. How would can I manage how each domain points to each website in nginx respectively? This is the crux of what I am trying to research

Comment: I updated my answer

Comment: Thank you very much for the detail in the answers, I managed to get it working by just pointing my domains directly at the webserver and nginx was able to handle it already. I think I had the misconception that I could just call the webserver with a URI that would load each website respectively.

Comment: You are very welcome. We are learning each day, and I've been in your shoes too with those concepts.